# jQuery move local files to another directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

I would like to create a function which will count the files from a directory.
If there are 5 files, move the oldest file to another directory.

I found a code [sample](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8652404#8652404), but it is not working for my case.

```
var myFileList = Folder("C:/Test").getFiles();
var folderCount = GetFoldersCount(myFileList) ;
$.writeln(folderCount);

function GetFoldersCount(fileList) {
    var folderCount = 0;
    console.log(folderCount);
    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        var myFile = myFileList[i];
        if (myFile instanceof Folder)
        folderCount++;
    }
    return folderCount
}
```

I am getting the error *"Folder" is not defined*.

Comment: The code you found is for *indesign scripting*. I don't think front end js can check a directory on users local computer. If it can, that can be a major security issue. But I can be wrong.

Comment: You can use [node file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to perform this task but in this case code will execute in in local terminal instead of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for this task, which works perfect for me.

I call the function with the initial directory:

```
moveErrorFiles('C:\\Folder1');
```

And below are the 2 simple functions I use.

```
function moveErrorFiles(fileDir) {
    var fileSysObj, file, folder, fileCounter, currentFile;
    var fileMumber = 0;

    fileSysObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    folder = fileSysObj.GetFolder(fileDir);
    fileCounter = new Enumerator(folder.files);

    for (; !fileCounter.atEnd(); fileCounter.moveNext()) {
        currentFile = fileCounter.item();
        fileMumber++;
        if (fileMumber > 5) {
            moveFile(currentFile);
        }
    }
}   //function moveErrorFiles() ends here

function moveFile(fileToMove) {
    var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var file = object.GetFile(fileToMove);
    file.Move("C:\\Folder2\\");
    console.log("File was moved successfully");
}   //function moveFile() ends here
```

Answer (score 2):

Its impossible directly access local files by JS for seccurity issue.
Another thing is that you can access files on drive over Ajax call and process 
 on response. Using Ajax you can send request what you want to do it on background.

You used example at InDesign forum. I dont know InDesign but I am not sure that it will work.
Otherwise look for documentation about HTML5 File API. Hope that you will find answer.
https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/

some examples:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/